# 500 Error on AppHarbor but downloaded build works on my machine

Tags: servicestack, appharbor

I'm using Visual Studio 2013 on Windows 8. I have a web service built off ServiceStack. Everything works fine on my machine but when deploying it to AppHarbor I get a 500 error. I set `customErrors mode="off"` and I still get a 500 error with no stack trace.

According to [AppHarbor's FAQ](http://support.appharbor.com/kb/getting-started/frequently-asked-questions):

> If enabling Custom Errors doesn't produce a stacktrace, then that's indicative of a configuration problem that prevents the ASP.NET runtime from initializing. You can debug such problems by deploying your app (either built locally or build output downloaded from AppHarbor) to a full IIS running on your local machine. You must configure the application pool to run in Integrated Pipeline mode to properly replicate AppHarbor's environment.

So I did this. I downloaded the build output from AppHarbor and ran it on my local IIS and it worked fine!

The AppHarbor Errors page says

> No errors to display.

And a AppHarbor's log session feature displays no meaningful information:

> 2013-12-31T09:55:20.886+00:00 appharbor web.1 Created new worker (version 1388526921)
>   2013-12-31T09:55:24.864+00:00 appharbor web.1 Warming up (version 1388526921)
>   2013-12-31T09:55:32.134+00:00 appharbor web.1 Web worker root URL returned HTTP status code 500 (Internal Server Error) (version 1388526921)

Any suggestions?

--
for references, here's an outline of my web.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
  For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=169433
  -->
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <sectionGroup name="dotNetOpenAuth" type="DotNetOpenAuth.Configuration.DotNetOpenAuthSection, DotNetOpenAuth">
      <section name="openid" type="DotNetOpenAuth.Configuration.OpenIdElement, DotNetOpenAuth" requirePermission="false" allowLocation="true" />
      <section name="oauth" type="DotNetOpenAuth.Configuration.OAuthElement, DotNetOpenAuth" requirePermission="false" allowLocation="true" />
      <section name="messaging" type="DotNetOpenAuth.Configuration.MessagingElement, DotNetOpenAuth" requirePermission="false" allowLocation="true" />
      <section name="reporting" type="DotNetOpenAuth.Configuration.ReportingElement, DotNetOpenAuth" requirePermission="false" allowLocation="true" />
    </sectionGroup>
  </configSections>
  <appSettings>
    ....
  </appSettings>
  <connectionStrings>
    ....
  </connectionStrings>
  <system.web>
    <customErrors mode="Off">
    </customErrors>
    <httpHandlers>
      <add path="*" type="ServiceStack.WebHost.Endpoints.ServiceStackHttpHandlerFactory, ServiceStack" verb="*" />
    </httpHandlers>
    <compilation debug="true" />
  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
    <handlers>
      <add path="*" name="ServiceStack.Factory" type="ServiceStack.WebHost.Endpoints.ServiceStackHttpHandlerFactory, ServiceStack" verb="*" preCondition="integratedMode" resourceType="Unspecified" allowPathInfo="true" />
    </handlers>
    <directoryBrowse enabled="true" />
  </system.webServer>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="MongoDB.Driver" publicKeyToken="f686731cfb9cc103" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.8.2.34" newVersion="1.8.2.34" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="MongoDB.Bson" publicKeyToken="f686731cfb9cc103" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.8.2.34" newVersion="1.8.2.34" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
    <!-- This prevents the Windows Event Log from frequently logging that HMAC1 is being used (when the other party needs it). -->
    <legacyHMACWarning enabled="0" />
  </runtime>
  <uri>
    <!-- The uri section is necessary to turn on .NET 3.5 support for IDN (international domain names),
         which is necessary for OpenID urls with unicode characters in the domain/host name. 
         It is also required to put the Uri class into RFC 3986 escaping mode, which OpenID and OAuth require. -->
    <idn enabled="All" />
    <iriParsing enabled="true" />
  </uri>
  <system.net>
    <defaultProxy enabled="true" />
    <settings>
    </settings>
  </system.net>
  <dotNetOpenAuth>
    <!-- This is an optional configuration section where aspects of dotnetopenauth can be customized. -->
    <!-- For a complete set of configuration options see http://www.dotnetopenauth.net/developers/code-snippets/configuration-options/ -->
    <openid>
      <relyingParty>
        <security requireSsl="false">
        </security>
        <behaviors>
          <!-- The following OPTIONAL behavior allows RPs to use SREG only, but be compatible
                         with OPs that use Attribute Exchange (in various formats). -->
          <add type="DotNetOpenAuth.OpenId.RelyingParty.Behaviors.AXFetchAsSregTransform, DotNetOpenAuth" />
        </behaviors>
      </relyingParty>
    </openid>
    <messaging>
      <untrustedWebRequest>
        <whitelistHosts>
        </whitelistHosts>
      </untrustedWebRequest>
    </messaging>
    <!-- Allow DotNetOpenAuth to publish usage statistics to library authors to improve the library. -->
    <reporting enabled="true" />
  </dotNetOpenAuth>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just a wild guess: (not much to go on) but I have had similar problems when, for example, I was using the IIS rewrite module on my local machine (and it worked fine), but when I uploaded to a host that did not have that add-on module installed, I would get a 500 error with very little to go on - sounds similar. It drove me crazy trying to find it.

So make sure whatever options/addons that you might have and be using locally in IIS are also installed on the host.

Similarly, make sure you understand everything that is being referenced/used in your web.config - that is likely the problem area.

Comment: I'm testing this on a brand new box, I had to setup IIS on it to test actually so no add-on modules. Not much in the web.config really, will update above.